# How can I make this query run efficiently?

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, we're trying to run:

```
SELECT day, AVG(value)/(1024*1024) FROM ( 
    SELECT value, UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp) as day, 
         PERCENTILE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day ORDER BY value ASC) as rank 
    FROM [Datastore.PerformanceDatum]
    WHERE type = "MemoryPerf"
) WHERE rank >= 0.9 AND rank <= 0.91 
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY day desc;
```

which returns a relatively small amount of data.  But we're getting the message:

```
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution. The query contained a GROUP BY operator, consider using GROUP EACH BY instead. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#groupby
```

What is making this query fail, the size of the subquery?  Is there some equivalent query we can do which avoids the problem?

---

Edit in response to comments: If I add GROUP EACH BY (and drop the outer ORDER BY), the query fails, claiming GROUP EACH BY is here not parallelizable.

Comment: Have you tried using a `GROUP EACH BY` as the error message suggested?

Comment: If I add GROUP EACH BY (and drop the outer ORDER BY), the query fails, claiming GROUP EACH BY is here not parallelizable.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Add that to your post. I'm just trying to help make it answerable and less likely to be put "on hold"

Comment: Does your inner query run? How about the outer query without grouping and averaging (just ordering and filtering by rank)?

Comment: The inner query and outer query without grouping+averaging would return far too much data to be allowed.  If I run the queries on smaller tables, any part of this works.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an equivalent query that works for me:

```
SELECT day, AVG(value)/(1024*1024) FROM (
SELECT data value, UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(dtimestamp) as day, 
         PERCENTILE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day ORDER BY value ASC) as rank 
    FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
    WHERE sensortype = "humidity"
) WHERE rank >= 0.9 AND rank <= 0.91 
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY day desc;
```

If I run only the inner query, I get 3,660,624 results. Is your dataset bigger than that?

The outer select gives me only 4 results when grouped by day. I'll try a different grouping to see if I can hit a limit there:

```
SELECT day, AVG(value)/(1024*1024) FROM (
SELECT data value, dtimestamp / 1000 as day, 
         PERCENTILE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY day ORDER BY value ASC) as rank 
    FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
    WHERE sensortype = "humidity"
) WHERE rank >= 0.9 AND rank <= 0.91 
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY day desc;
```

Runs too, now with 57,862 different groups.

I tried different combinations to get to the same error. I was able to get the same error as you doubling the amount of initial data. An easy "hack" to double the amount of data is changing:

```
    FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
```

To:

```
    FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13], [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
```

Then I get the same error. How much data do you have? Can you apply an additional filter? As you are already partitioning the percentile_rank by day, can you add an additional query to only analyze a fraction of the days (for example, only last month)?

Comment: Analyzing only a fraction of the days is the hack I'm doing right now, but it bristles me a bit since since the actual returned data is quite small.